# Propensity score matching and linear regression covariates

Tags: regression, mixed-model, linear-model, propensity-scores, predictor

Suppose I use PSM to balance confounders for treatment effect in observational studies, and the logistic model for the PS includes age, gender, comorbidities.

And then use either stratification or matching or weighting (eg in tutorial by http://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/mark.lunt/) followed by PS matched linear regression.

Can the PS matched linear regression then have age, gender, comorbidities as covariates?

Conceptually it seems to me that you should be able to, but not if PS is used for model reduction and the PS is added as a covariate (as some people do https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4004383/).

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you certainly can! This is called the "doubly robust" approach and is recommended by many authors. You essentially run the linear regression model you would have run had you not performed the propensity score analysis, but you do so on your propensity score adjusted sample. See [Stuart (2010)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2943670/), section 5 for an introduction to this idea.

Comment: Thanks Noah that's very helpful. Have you got any good references explaining benefits of PSM over "adjusting for baseline as a covariates"?

Comment: Gary King has written a fair amount about this. See Ho, Imai, King & Stuart (2007) and Nielson & King (2016).

Comment: +1. I would suggest that you not only *can* but *should* do this!